# silent renew error Frame window timed out on refresh token

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using Identity Server 4 asp net core backend and React SPA for frontend. I'm getting 'silent renew error Frame window timed out' in console of browser when refreshing token. Please help. Below is my code.

[image]

My authConst.js

```
export const IDENTITY_CONFIG = {
  authority: "https://localhost:44343/",
  client_id: "rentalstoreclient",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
  silent_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
  post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:4200/",
  audience: "Rental Store",
  response_type: "id_token token",
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  loadUserInfo: false,
  scope: "openid profile"
};

export const METADATA_OIDC = {
  issuer: "https://localhost:44343",
  jwks_uri: "https://localhost:44343/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  authorization_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/authorize",
  token_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/token",
  userinfo_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/userinfo",
  end_session_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/endsession",
  check_session_iframe: "https://localhost:44343/connect/checksession",
  revocation_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/revocation",
  introspection_endpoint: "https://localhost:44343/connect/introspect"
};
```

My authService.jsx

```
import { IDENTITY_CONFIG, METADATA_OIDC } from "../utils/authConst";
import { UserManager, WebStorageStateStore, Log } from "oidc-client";

export default class AuthService {
  UserManager;
  accessToken;

  constructor() {
    this.UserManager = new UserManager({
      ...IDENTITY_CONFIG,
      userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
      metadata: {
        ...METADATA_OIDC
      }
    });
    // Logger
    Log.logger = console;
    Log.level = Log.DEBUG;

    this.UserManager.events.addUserLoaded(user => {
      this.accessToken = user.access_token;
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", user.access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("id_token", user.id_token);
      this.setUserInfo({
        accessToken: this.accessToken,
        idToken: user.id_token
      });
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("signin-oidc") !== -1) {
        this.navigateToScreen();
      }
    });
    this.UserManager.events.addSilentRenewError(e => {
      console.log("silent renew error", e.message);
    });

    this.UserManager.events.addAccessTokenExpired(() => {
      console.log("token expired");
      this.signinSilent();
    });
  }

  signinRedirectCallback = () => {
    this.UserManager.signinRedirectCallback().then(() => {
      "";
    });
  };

  getUser = async () => {
    const user = await this.UserManager.getUser();
    if (!user) {
      return await this.UserManager.signinRedirectCallback();
    }
    return user;
  };

  parseJwt = token => {
    const base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
    const base64 = base64Url.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/");
    return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
  };

  setUserInfo = authResult => {
    const data = this.parseJwt(this.accessToken);

    this.setSessionInfo(authResult);
    this.setUser(data);
  };

  signinRedirect = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("redirectUri", window.location.pathname);
    this.UserManager.signinRedirect({});
  };

  setUser = data => {
    localStorage.setItem("userId", data.sub);
  };

  navigateToScreen = () => {
    const redirectUri = !!localStorage.getItem("redirectUri")
      ? localStorage.getItem("redirectUri")
      : "/en/dashboard";
    const language = "/" + redirectUri.split("/")[1];

    window.location.replace(language + "/dashboard");
  };

  setSessionInfo(authResult) {
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResult.idToken);
  }

  isAuthenticated = () => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    return !!access_token;
  };

  signinSilent = () => {
    this.UserManager.signinSilent()
      .then(user => {
        console.log("signed in", user);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  signinSilentCallback = () => {
    console.log("Token renew method");
    this.UserManager.signinSilentCallback();
  };

  createSigninRequest = () => {
    return this.UserManager.createSigninRequest();
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.UserManager.signoutRedirect({
      id_token_hint: localStorage.getItem("id_token")
    });
    this.UserManager.clearStaleState();
  };

  signoutRedirectCallback = () => {
    this.UserManager.signoutRedirectCallback().then(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      // window.location.replace(process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL);
      window.location.replace("https://localhost:4200/");
    });
    this.UserManager.clearStaleState();
  };
}
```

My authProvider.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import AuthService from "../services/authService";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
    signinRedirectCallback: () => ({}),
    logout: () => ({}),
    signoutRedirectCallback: () => ({}),
    isAuthenticated: () => ({}),
    signinRedirect: () => ({}),
    signinSilentCallback: () => ({}),
    createSigninRequest: () => ({})
});

export const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;

export class AuthProvider extends Component {
    authService;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.authService = new AuthService();
    }
    render() {
        return <AuthContext.Provider value={this.authService}>{this.props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
    }
}
```

My silentRenew.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import { AuthConsumer } from "../../providers/authProvider";

export const SilentRenew = () => (
  <AuthConsumer>
    {({ signinSilentCallback }) => {
      signinSilentCallback();
      return <span>loading</span>;
    }}
  </AuthConsumer>
);
```

My Config.cs in Identity Server

```
public static List<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "Rental Store",
                    ClientId="rentalstoreclient",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RedirectUris =new List<string>
                    {
                        "https://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
                        "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew"
                    },
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 180,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new[]{
                        "https://localhost:4200/" },
                    AllowedScopes = new []
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "roles",
                        "rentalstoreapi"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

My startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                //.AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            services.AddCors();

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                });

            //services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => { o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(6); });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
```

ASP.NET Core Web Server log

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44343/connect/authorize?client_id=rentalstoreclient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fredirect-silentrenew&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile&state=0c0958e3d474469da8a92a8735e0e3dd&nonce=50ca805cfa6942cb8c6eb82826a459a0&prompt=none&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Il9xU3djLUJ4WURFTkVoSWxqM0cxenciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTMwODk5MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNDMiLCJhdWQiOiJyZW50YWxzdG9yZWNsaWVudCIsIm5vbmNlIjoiOGIyYjEwNGFkNmUzNGI1ZGI4OGU2Y2Q0ZTZmZmQ5MmUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJDMS1lWUNNejJfa1ZrRkF5MHgwUHRnIiwic19oYXNoIjoiZ0FmcUNOTFZPU1J4cWNKYXNCSjlsZyIsInNpZCI6InhVWEdBQ05oRDRScGRyeG01T242ZXciLCJzdWIiOiIyNzBjMDBiNS04NTIzLTRkOGItOWJmYS03YTc2ZmJhMDFkZWEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwiYW1yIjpbIm1mYSJdfQ.WQg370cjNiFyR_PaSpqDUo4E87w2rtjjz82CsdTqhX9H-U-NXKoJz8MFgWpc22iX7Zxjr0q8H4yosXF4oH5GcGHeuggOXf0loTjuJYUtIA3uHc0ps-0DbqyAC2tJsCWSEkb72LSyRNhbZsOQpk0vt61Jbu0G4NYGwrdubWBk3DPlsp8gQWY8Dc609w_CPIMkLAwhC4ng3EtmuA4Rlsd8PNQWg-NtUyytbxtvpUoUJcACjAqnN43dn41mrEBavFt0DmvMAZB3P8Q-UhWsixfUzQvd-P_0W5VBYmZX5KPORmWnx-HxZ1WXOtuaSbxXoRTLXc0bFdIVzkAVcXsUxr6sqw  
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Start authorize request
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      User in authorize request: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Start authorize request protocol validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client rentalstoreclient succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "rentalstoreclient",
        "ClientName": "Rental Store",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "https://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
          "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea",
        "ResponseType": "id_token token",
        "ResponseMode": "fragment",
        "GrantType": "implicit",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "0c0958e3d474469da8a92a8735e0e3dd",
        "Nonce": "50ca805cfa6942cb8c6eb82826a459a0",
        "PromptMode": "none",
        "SessionId": "xUXGACNhD4Rpdrxm5On6ew",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "rentalstoreclient",
          "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
          "response_type": "id_token token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "state": "0c0958e3d474469da8a92a8735e0e3dd",
          "nonce": "50ca805cfa6942cb8c6eb82826a459a0",
          "prompt": "none",
          "id_token_hint": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
      WHERE ([a].[Id] = @__p_0) AND @__p_0 IS NOT NULL
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService[0]
      Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
      Creating Implicit Flow response.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for access token for client: rentalstoreclient
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for access token for subject: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId]
      FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a]
      WHERE ([a].[UserId] = @__user_Id_0) AND @__user_Id_0 IS NOT NULL
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a0].[Name]
      FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a]
      INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [a0] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a0].[Id]
      WHERE ([a].[UserId] = @__userId_0) AND @__userId_0 IS NOT NULL
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for identity token for subject: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea and client: rentalstoreclient
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Authorize endpoint response
      {
        "SubjectId": "270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea",
        "ClientId": "rentalstoreclient",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
        "State": "0c0958e3d474469da8a92a8735e0e3dd",
        "Scope": "openid profile"
      }
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 123.039ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44343/connect/checksession  
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint[0]
      Rendering check session result
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 33.417300000000004ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44343/connect/authorize?client_id=rentalstoreclient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fredirect-silentrenew&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile&state=853714bd11e546e7a87e9ca17bcde9b0&nonce=8fa05fdd96bd45b1a2f1f649d3248d9f&prompt=none&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Il9xU3djLUJ4WURFTkVoSWxqM0cxenciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTMwODk5MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNDMiLCJhdWQiOiJyZW50YWxzdG9yZWNsaWVudCIsIm5vbmNlIjoiOGIyYjEwNGFkNmUzNGI1ZGI4OGU2Y2Q0ZTZmZmQ5MmUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJDMS1lWUNNejJfa1ZrRkF5MHgwUHRnIiwic19oYXNoIjoiZ0FmcUNOTFZPU1J4cWNKYXNCSjlsZyIsInNpZCI6InhVWEdBQ05oRDRScGRyeG01T242ZXciLCJzdWIiOiIyNzBjMDBiNS04NTIzLTRkOGItOWJmYS03YTc2ZmJhMDFkZWEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwiYW1yIjpbIm1mYSJdfQ.WQg370cjNiFyR_PaSpqDUo4E87w2rtjjz82CsdTqhX9H-U-NXKoJz8MFgWpc22iX7Zxjr0q8H4yosXF4oH5GcGHeuggOXf0loTjuJYUtIA3uHc0ps-0DbqyAC2tJsCWSEkb72LSyRNhbZsOQpk0vt61Jbu0G4NYGwrdubWBk3DPlsp8gQWY8Dc609w_CPIMkLAwhC4ng3EtmuA4Rlsd8PNQWg-NtUyytbxtvpUoUJcACjAqnN43dn41mrEBavFt0DmvMAZB3P8Q-UhWsixfUzQvd-P_0W5VBYmZX5KPORmWnx-HxZ1WXOtuaSbxXoRTLXc0bFdIVzkAVcXsUxr6sqw  
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Start authorize request
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      User in authorize request: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Start authorize request protocol validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client rentalstoreclient succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "rentalstoreclient",
        "ClientName": "Rental Store",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "https://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
          "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea",
        "ResponseType": "id_token token",
        "ResponseMode": "fragment",
        "GrantType": "implicit",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "853714bd11e546e7a87e9ca17bcde9b0",
        "Nonce": "8fa05fdd96bd45b1a2f1f649d3248d9f",
        "PromptMode": "none",
        "SessionId": "xUXGACNhD4Rpdrxm5On6ew",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "rentalstoreclient",
          "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
          "response_type": "id_token token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "state": "853714bd11e546e7a87e9ca17bcde9b0",
          "nonce": "8fa05fdd96bd45b1a2f1f649d3248d9f",
          "prompt": "none",
          "id_token_hint": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
      WHERE ([a].[Id] = @__p_0) AND @__p_0 IS NOT NULL
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService[0]
      Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
      Creating Implicit Flow response.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for access token for client: rentalstoreclient
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for access token for subject: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId]
      FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a]
      WHERE ([a].[UserId] = @__user_Id_0) AND @__user_Id_0 IS NOT NULL
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a0].[Name]
      FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a]
      INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [a0] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a0].[Id]
      WHERE ([a].[UserId] = @__userId_0) AND @__userId_0 IS NOT NULL
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for identity token for subject: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea and client: rentalstoreclient
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Authorize endpoint response
      {
        "SubjectId": "270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea",
        "ClientId": "rentalstoreclient",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
        "State": "853714bd11e546e7a87e9ca17bcde9b0",
        "Scope": "openid profile"
      }
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 98.1836ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44343/connect/checksession  
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint[0]
      Rendering check session result
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 27.354200000000002ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44343/connect/authorize?client_id=rentalstoreclient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fredirect-silentrenew&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile&state=b31ce852884c49cb8be8068283a32c4d&nonce=60a6b32a15994de0b6f7fd4d488b4dc0&prompt=none&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Il9xU3djLUJ4WURFTkVoSWxqM0cxenciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTMwODk5MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNDMiLCJhdWQiOiJyZW50YWxzdG9yZWNsaWVudCIsIm5vbmNlIjoiOGIyYjEwNGFkNmUzNGI1ZGI4OGU2Y2Q0ZTZmZmQ5MmUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJDMS1lWUNNejJfa1ZrRkF5MHgwUHRnIiwic19oYXNoIjoiZ0FmcUNOTFZPU1J4cWNKYXNCSjlsZyIsInNpZCI6InhVWEdBQ05oRDRScGRyeG01T242ZXciLCJzdWIiOiIyNzBjMDBiNS04NTIzLTRkOGItOWJmYS03YTc2ZmJhMDFkZWEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzEzMDg2OTIsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwiYW1yIjpbIm1mYSJdfQ.WQg370cjNiFyR_PaSpqDUo4E87w2rtjjz82CsdTqhX9H-U-NXKoJz8MFgWpc22iX7Zxjr0q8H4yosXF4oH5GcGHeuggOXf0loTjuJYUtIA3uHc0ps-0DbqyAC2tJsCWSEkb72LSyRNhbZsOQpk0vt61Jbu0G4NYGwrdubWBk3DPlsp8gQWY8Dc609w_CPIMkLAwhC4ng3EtmuA4Rlsd8PNQWg-NtUyytbxtvpUoUJcACjAqnN43dn41mrEBavFt0DmvMAZB3P8Q-UhWsixfUzQvd-P_0W5VBYmZX5KPORmWnx-HxZ1WXOtuaSbxXoRTLXc0bFdIVzkAVcXsUxr6sqw  
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Start authorize request
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      User in authorize request: 270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Start authorize request protocol validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client rentalstoreclient succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "rentalstoreclient",
        "ClientName": "Rental Store",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "https://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
          "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "270c00b5-8523-4d8b-9bfa-7a76fba01dea",
        "ResponseType": "id_token token",
        "ResponseMode": "fragment",
        "GrantType": "implicit",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "b31ce852884c49cb8be8068283a32c4d",
        "Nonce": "60a6b32a15994de0b6f7fd4d488b4dc0",
        "PromptMode": "none",
        "SessionId": "xUXGACNhD4Rpdrxm5On6ew",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "rentalstoreclient",
          "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew",
          "response_type": "id_token token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "state": "b31ce852884c49cb8be8068283a32c4d",
          "nonce": "60a6b32a15994de0b6f7fd4d488b4dc0",
          "prompt": "none",
          "id_token_hint": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
```

Comment: What actually happens? Does the authorize endpoint request fail? Does your IDS4 log any errors?

Comment: @mackie I updated the question and attached asp net core web server output

Comment: One gotcha that I encountered is that by default the samesite property on the auth cookie is not set to `none`. If it's set to `strict` or `lax` then it will prevent iframe-based `prompt=none` requests from working because the browser will not send the auth cookie. Can you confirm that your primary auth cookie in IDS4 is set to `SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;`?

Comment: @mackie Check my updated startup class.

Comment: @mackie Check my updated startup class.

Comment: That all looks OK so it's likely it's the `https://localhost:4200/redirect-silentrenew` endpoint not doing the correct thing. Ultimately it'll need to spin up a `UserManager` instance and call `signinSilentCallback()`. I'm not familiar enough with React to say if your code is correct from what you've posted.

Comment: @Mick Have you fixed the issue? I have same problem

Comment: No not fixed yet.

Comment: Yeah we have the same issues randomly with some users and can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: @Julia Have you raised any github issues? I'm facing same problem my code is very similar to yours. I can't find the issue :(

Comment: Is there anyone found any solution? I am also having the same issue

Comment: I have the same problem. CORS allows all. Cookies are set correctly. Oauth-Server responses are correctly.

Comment: try adding the offline_access scope

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by calling this.signinSilent() function in my addAccessTokenExpired event.